# How to add a value and its index to a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I googled and most of the answers is about adding a value to a series but not update the index.

Here is my series with date string as its index like this

```
2022-01-01  1
2022-01-02  7
2022-01-03  3
```

Now I like to add new value of 10 into this series with new index of 2022-01-04 date string. so the series becomes

```
2022-01-01  1
2022-01-02  7
2022-01-03  3
2022-01-04  10
```

How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the index value as a subscript, for example:

```
>>> aa = pd.Series({"foo": 1})
>>> aa
foo    1
dtype: int64
>>> aa["bar"] = 2
>>> aa
foo    1
bar    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just something like:

```
new_row = pd.Series(new_value, index=[index_of_new_value])
series = pd.concat([series, new_row])
```

I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: awesome! that is exactly what I wanted, Thank you betterflyknife. what is the difference between pd.concat() and append(), are they the same?

Comment: append() has been recently deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your series is called `ser`, here is a proposition with [**`pandas.DatetimeIndex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and [**`pandas.Series.reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) :

```
idx = pd.date_range('01-01-2022', '01-04-2022')
ser.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(ser.index)
ser = ser.reindex(idx, fill_value=10)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(ser)

2022-01-01     1
2022-01-02     7
2022-01-03     3
2022-01-04    10
```